# error while starting my session (profile error?)

Tags: 16.04, user-profile

I am kind of new to Ubuntu, I recently installed it but every time I open my session there is [this weird message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5KyC.jpg) that pops up.

So it is in french but it says :

```
error found while charging /home/zagdoun[=user]/.profile 
/home/zagdoun/.profile : line 21: -e: command not found

Hence your session will not be configured properly.You should resolve this matter asap.
```

For the record i installed ubuntu via a usb key and it is not a partition .

Also when i use Python or TensorFlow i get this warning on my terminal :

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

When i type `cat ~/.profile` this is the output

```
    # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
-e 
#ADDED BY SYNCPY2
PATH=/home/zagdoun/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: remove the `-e` there and try again

Comment: It worked when i do this

Comment: Great glad it did.